# Conceptual question about data corruption and mounting

Tags: linux, mount, corruption, data

If we have a partition `/dev/sda1`, and mount it to a mount point (i.e. `/mnt`), we can then use the files and folders under `/mnt`.
Before changing the partition `/dev/sda1` I umount `/mnt`, and then perform disk resizing operations.

When`/mnt` has been unmounted I am confused as to how 'data corruption' can occur because the filesystem (`/mnt)` has been unmounted.

i.e. after sometimes resizing the disk I get errors after I run `e2fsck` on the unmounted partition - does this mean the actual data is stored on the partition `/dev/sda1` or is it meta-data of some sort?

Also in the future if I wish to make a backup would it make more sense to use `dd` to backup the partition or use `cp` to copy the data under `/mnt`?

```
fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
fsck.ext3: Group descriptors look bad... trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext3: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext3
filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext3
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:

e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `dd` works low level, So When you want to resize partition or change its block address, dd is wrost options.Use a command such as tar or cp or so on.Try to mount looply your dd file.

Comment: I don't get what you mean “does this mean …”, also can you show us the errors from `e2fsck`.

Comment: @ams; with respect to backups; I don't think `dd` makes sense for anything else than raw backups (no individual access or restoration), and `cp` makes only sense for small and isolated data. You probably want something more sophisticated. There are a couple options; you may want to have a look into `rsnapshot`, for example.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh why would I use a loop device? I'm guessing that's what "mount looply" means. Also a filesystem cannot be mounted to a /dev/loopX device can it?

Comment: @richard I have posted a sample error I get above, however normally I try to restore from an alternative superblock. My original question still holds though, how can a partition be corrupted if the data has been unmounted? I don't understand how this kind of error can occur:
`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck.ext4 -vy /dev/sda1
Inode table for group 0 is not in group.  (block 2440124416)
WARNING: SEVERE DATA LOSS POSSIBLE.
Relocate? yes`
when we can just mount say /mnt to a different partition and restore from there. What data loss is it talking about?

Comment: @ams, looply for ccpy your old data.